# Open a window wherever system focus is using Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm using GitHub's Electron to open a small new window whenever a user hits a global shortcut.

Currently, that window opens wherever the user's cursor is, but this is a little unintuitive when a user is typing in a text area, as I would prefer the box to open where the cursor's focus is.

From reading the documentation there doesn't appear to be a way to grab the cursor's location (eg. the caret where the user is typing) rather than the pointer's location.  Is it possible?

Comment: This is definitely not possible with normal Electron and (at least on OS X) is very hard to accomplish even with native APIs. I believe it would require hooking into the window manager.

Comment: I want to have my Electron app open right below (or above, if not enough room) the user's blinking text cursor from before they opened/focused my Electron app. Did you ever figure this out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

after the window has been created, you can call a setPosition within a onload, or onready event.

```
ready () {
  require('electron').remote.getCurrentWindow().setPosition(x, y)
}
```

I hope that helps somewhat.

also, look at http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/screen/

console.log(screen). I am pretty sure there is a method to return cursor position.

Comment: It returns the pointer location, not the focus location (eg if you're typing in a text area)