# How to get position of text cursor (NOT mouse cursor) from when user pressed global hotkey to bring my Electron app into focus?

Tags: electron

I have an emoji picker Electron app.

Assume a user has opened this Electron app and left it running in the background.

They are currently typing text (have a blinking text cursor) in an external app, such as in TextEdit or in a text field in a browser.

Then they press a global keyboard hotkey, which brings my emoji picker Electron app into focus.

1. How can I set the position of my app to match the position of where their text cursor was in the external app?
2. When a user selects an emoji, I want my app to write the emoji to wherever the user's text cursor (not mouse pointer) was before they focused on my app.

How can I do that?

---

(E.g. I want it to work like <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> does on [Mac](https://www.switchingtomac.com/macos/how-to-open-the-emoji-keyboard-on-macos/).)

`screen.getCursorScreenPoint()` seems to only provide [*mouse* cursor position](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/screen).

P.S. If the answer requires my app to use the user's clipboard, I want to first save a backup of whatever the user has in their clipboard, then restore their clipboard contents after pasting the emoji.

Old related questions without real answers:

- [Open a window wherever system focus is using Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36079782/open-a-window-wherever-system-focus-is-using-electron)
- [How to get cursor position in electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69732341/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-electron)

Comment: The "text cursor" is commonly known as [caret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_navigation)

Comment: @Cleptus Interesting! I'd only heard caret as ^ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret, so I bet there is a lot of confusion with that word. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) itself provides direct access to the text cursor position in external applications.
A possible workaround is using native modules or external scripts (like in Python, AppleScript for macOS, etc.) to get the text cursor position from the system. But... this method might not be reliable or consistent across different applications and operating systems.

Same for directly controlling the text cursor in an external application: this is outside the capabilities of Electron.

A practical approach would be to use the clipboard:

- Save the current clipboard contents.
- Copy the selected emoji to the clipboard.
- Simulate a "Paste" keyboard command to insert the emoji.
- Restore the original clipboard contents.

You could use a Node.js packages such as [`robotjs`](https://robotjs.io/docs/) for simulating keyboard events and [`clipboardy`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/clipboardy) for clipboard operations.

```js
const { clipboard } = require('electron');
const robot = require('robotjs');
const clipboardy = require('clipboardy');

// Save current clipboard contents
let originalClipboard = clipboardy.readSync();

// Function to insert emoji
function insertEmoji(emoji) {
  // Copy emoji to clipboard
  clipboardy.writeSync(emoji);

  // Simulate 'Paste' command
  robot.keyTap('v', ['control']); // Use 'command' for macOS

  // Restore original clipboard contents
  clipboardy.writeSync(originalClipboard);
}

// Usage
// When user selects an emoji in your app
insertEmoji("");
```

The compromise is that you are not being able to precisely position the app near the text cursor due to limitations in Electron's capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've spent a lot of time trying to get this to work, but no luck. Clipboardy doesn't work well with https://electron-react-boilerplate.js.org/. But as your code mentions, `electron` has `clipboard` available anyway. https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/clipboard It works fine (in console logs) except that robotjs doesn't paste it to the external app, even though my boilerplate has `accelerator: "CmdOrCtrl+V"` in a menu like https://pracucci.com/atom-electron-enable-copy-and-paste.html. To be clear, I'm trying to paste the emoji _outside_ my Electron app. Thanks 

Comment: @Ryan Yes, that code was just to illustrate a possible workaround, but I have not tested it directly. Maybe you need to switch the active Windows before the keyTap, in order for the paste action to be done outside your Electron app.

Comment: That would make sense. I will search for how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: I've called `app?.hide();` which is probably what I want. And I set an event listener `app.on('browser-window-blur` which seems to work. But the robotjs part still doesn't seem to do anything in that event handler.

Comment: @Ryan hide and blur are more for masking an app. You would need to bring the target app in foreground, for it to be the recipient of a paste keyTap event.